# How to prevent VZW drive from mounting when I connect my HTC Incredible to USB

Tags: htc-droid-incredible, usb-connection-mode

Since the Froyo upgrade, when I connect my HTC Incredible, with the USB settings set to "Charge Only" to my computer with a USB cable, the phone still mounts a CD type drive that will install HTC Sync drivers.  This prevents my phone from using the SD card.

How can I stop this from happening?  Like I said, my phone is set to "Charge Only".

Comment: Do you have an app installed that makes your phone do that, like doubleTwist?

Comment: Winamp has that feature too. I hate it. (At least both apps let you turn it off)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to root your phone with [Unrevoked](http://unrevoked.com/) and remove the CDROM.ISO file located in /system/etc/  That's the only way to prevent that.

The neat upside is that once you've rooted, you can replace that CDROM.ISO with any other ISO you'd like to auto-mount.